# Group of kids linked in some way by an Orb granting supernatural powers

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in the late 80's/early 90's called "The Orb" and have been unable to find it anywhere. It may have published under a different name in other parts of the world.

The plot surrounds a group of kids (four if i recall correctly) from different parts of the world who are linked in some way by an orb. The orb helps them find each other and grants supernatural powers to them in order to save the world in some way from something.

If I recall this right the in end of the book, it turns out that dolphins (or a specific group of dolphins) are either aliens who leave or who are wise have caused the orb to find these kids and are precognisant.

Any help would be great.